# ComboBox changing style when manually drawing items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am having a weird issue here where my combobox is changing its style from `DropDownList` to `DropDown` and only visually. Checking the `DropDownStyle` property of my combobox shows its set to `DropDownList`.

Basically here is what I am doing:

```
void InitComponents()
{
            ddlInterval.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            ddlInterval.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(DrawIntervalItems);
            List<IntervalItem> backupIntervalsList = new List<IntervalItem>();
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(5, GetIntervalString(5)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(15, GetIntervalString(15)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(30, GetIntervalString(30)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(60, GetIntervalString(60)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(120, GetIntervalString(120)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(240, GetIntervalString(240)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(480, GetIntervalString(480)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(720, GetIntervalString(720)));
            IntervalsList.Add(new IntervalItem(1440, GetIntervalString(1440)));
            ddlInterval.DataSource = IntervalsList;
            ddlInterval.DisplayMember = "Name";
            ddlInterval.ValueMember = "Value";
}

 void DrawIntervalItems(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if(_bDisableItems)
            {
                switch (e.Index)
                {
                    case 5:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                        {
                            string s = ddlInterval.GetItemText(ddlInterval.Items[e.Index]);
                            e.DrawBackground();
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(s, ddlInterval.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        {

                            string s = ddlInterval.GetItemText(ddlInterval.Items[e.Index]);
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(s, ddlInterval.Font, Brushes.LightSlateGray, e.Bounds);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is an image that shows the difference between two of my comboboxes. Note that both have their `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDownList` yet only the one on the bottom has its items manually drawn:

[image: Difference between comboboxes]

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You may be able to make use of the [`ComboBoxRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxrenderer.aspx) class to paint the control correctly. Make sure to check `Application.RenderWithVisualStyles` first. (EDIT: Better yet, check `ComboBoxRenderer.IsSupported` as the code sample does. I overlooked this property.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 ddlInterval.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal;
```

instead of:

```
 ddlInterval.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

Comment: If I set the drawMode to normal, the DrawItem event will not get raised

Comment: You set DrawItem event only for ddlBackupInterval.not for ddlInterval?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, ddlBackupInterval and ddlInterval are one and the same